# Implementation of Tree using queue(linked list implementation)

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, tree, queue, binary-tree

I am trying to code preorder traversal for a tree using queue(linked list implementation)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:
    int data;
    Node *rchild;
    Node *lchild;
};

class Queue{
   private:
 Node *front;
 Node *rear;
 
 
 public:
 Queue();
 void enqueue(Node* x);
 int dequeue();
 bool isEmpty();
 bool isFull();
 void display();
  
};
 
void enqueue(Node *x){
Node *t = new Node;
if(t == NULL) cout<<"Overflow!;
else{
rear++;
rear->data = x;
```

Now when i am doing rear->data = x; this statement is not valid because x is not an integer.

How should i proceed?

Comment: Your code snippet ends suddenly, with missing closing braces... Could you also improve the indentation?

Comment: Even if you implement the queue correctly, how will that help to do a preorder traversal? It will help to do a breadth-first traversal, but not preorder.

Comment: And if you really want a queue, why don't you just use the queue from the standard C++ library?